# Define "dynamic" enum

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I'm working on this project and I have a large number of "services" to execute. I need to have this service codes so I can verifiy and make decisions according to selected services by it's code.

I'm tring to define this **enum** and get its values from the web.config so I can change them easily.

```
public enum ServiceCodes
{
    Transfer= Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["servTransfer"]),
    ChangePlate= Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["servChangePlate"])
}
```

But I get this error: The expression must be constant. (because of the Conversion)

What can I do? (Or you can suggest me totally different approaches.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just go ahead and define a static class like this:

```
public static class ServiceCodes
{
  readonly static int Transfer = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["servTransfer"])
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28VS.80%29.aspx) states that enum values are constant. An alternative approach is to declare a class with `static readonly` members.

If you still need the type safety provided by an enum, you could use a slightly complex approach:

```
public class ServiceCodes {

    public static readonly ServiceCodes Transfer = new ServiceCodes(Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["servTransfer"]));
    public static readonly ServiceCodes ChangePlate = new ServiceCodes(Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["servChangePlate"]));

    internal int Code {get; private set;}

    private ServiceCodes(int code) {
        Code = code;
    }
}
```

Then, a method like:

```
public void SomeAction(ServiceCodes serviceCode) {
    //....  
}
```

could be called like this:

```
SomeAction(ServiceCodes.Transfer);
```

But, given the complexity (compared with the gain), I would go with the first approach.