# Define constants (enum like) for using in all projects and easy maintenance

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5

I had this question solved:
[Define "dynamic" enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898217/define-dynamic-enum)

Which I needed to get some Codes defined in the web.config from a class in **App_Code** for easy call. Well, the problem now is that I need to use this same Codes inside my business classes (and they won't access Web.config keys..

Accepting any solutions or different approaches

Comment: Is the project that your business classes are in referenced by the web project? If so, the business classes CAN read your web.config keys, if you're executing the web project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are building a non-web app, the code in the previous sample:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["servTransfer"])
```

will read from your .exe.config file just like it reads from the web.config file.

Comment: then it will read from web.config - the ConfigurationManager knows where to look in different kinds of apps. I use this also - I have a dll which is used in both web and exe apps - it reads config info from the appropriate config file without having to do anything special

Answer (score 0):

If all of you services are running on the same machine you can define what you need in the machine config file.  If they are on different machine you could use a wcf service for common values.